# UILabel size to fit

Tags: iphone

I have a problem involving `UILabel`'s `sizeToFit` method:

```
UILabel *questionLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,320)];
questionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
questionLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
questionLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
questionLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
questionLabel.tag=1;
questionLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
questionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[questionLabel sizeToFit];
[myView addSubview:questionLabel];
```

I had written this code for displaying my data. But if I write: `[questionLabel sizeToFit]` my data does not display properly. If I remove `[questionLabel sizeToFit]` then it is displaying but it only shows half the data.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: why are you setting the number of lines as 0 statically? Instead you can calculate the width or height or both using font size by initializing with CGRectZero.

Comment: thanks for giving reply. can you expalin the above sentence clearly

Comment: Well , I know I'm late , but maybe this helps: 'sizeToFit' does not work with 'UILabel' with multiple lines. You can use a 'UITextView' for that but you have to be sure that the text view's size is larger than needed. Like this : set view's height = 'MAXFLOAT' and then call 'sizeToFit'. If you want to keep it a label , you need to use the 'sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:' way. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

```
NSString *yourString = @"write your label text here";
CGSize s = [yourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
questionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
```

Check if it helps.

Comment: This No longer works in ios 8, as this method has been deprecated

Comment: Use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping instead of UILineBreakModeWordWrap which is deprecated! :)

Comment: sizeWithFont: is now deprecated - so this is no longer correct

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to use taus-iDeveloper answer to compute the size of a label.
I just want to say that the reason your code is not working is because you didn't set text to your UILabel so sizeToFit returns CGSizeZero (so it doesn't appear on screen). You have to set text before using sizeToFit.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if AutoLayout is on then size to fit not work

Answer (score 0):

i googled d above problem and came across some info that sizeToFit seems to be a bug and it has been reported to apple already.
So as a workaround u can use this code:

```
NSString * myText = [NSString stringWithString:@"some text"];

CGFloat constrainedSize = 265.0f;

UIFont * myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:19]; 

CGSize textSize = [myText sizeWithFont: myFont
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constrainedSize, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];



CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake (0, 0, textSize.width, textSize.height);

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];

[label setFont:myFont];

[label setText:myText];
```

Comment: Thanks for keeping effort but still the same problem is comming

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when using sizeToFit with a UILabel, in InterfaceBuilder you need to change the Autoshrink property from 'Fixed Font Size' to 'Minimum Font Size'. I usually then set its value to 0.5 to be sure its working properly.

Answer (score -1):

just make sure you increase the number of lines of the label. Instead of

`questionLable.numberOfLines = 0;` make use of

`questionLable.numberOfLines = 4;` 
As it will force the system to compute the smallest width possible for 4 lines.

You can achieve this via the Xib file too..

Comment: The problem is i cant able to see the data. if i write [questionLable sizeToFit]